# Python if statement to skip dictionary key when creating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

My code looks like this:

```
def createEventBody(name,description,attendees,location, eventColor = None):
    eventBody = {
              'Name': name, #EventName
              'Color': eventColor,
              'location': location,
              'description':description,
              'attendees': [],
              }
```

The thing is, I want to add some logic so that the key 'Color' is not included if eventColor = None.
I was thinking something like this:

```
def createEventBody(name,description,attendees,location, eventColor = None):
    eventBody = {
              'Name': name, #EventName
              ('Color': eventColor) if eventColor != None else pass,
              'location': location,
              'description':description,
              'attendees': [],
              }
```

However 'pass' doesn't allow me to "skip" that key.
How could I fix this?

Comment: Set the `Color` entry in an if statement after the `eventBody` dict is created.

Comment: You can either 1) not include it in the inline initialization, then later add it if your condition is satisfied, or 2) include it anyway in your inline initialization, then later delete it if your condition is not satisfied. I never saw an inline initialization of list/dict/set/whatever with conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x if y else z` is a conditional expression: it is a way of issuing a value that depends on a condition. It is not suitable for doing something or not doing it. That is what an if statement is for.

Set the Color entry in an if statement after the eventBody dict is created.

```
eventBody = {
          'Name': name,
          'location': location,
          'description':description,
          'attendees': [],
}
if eventColor is not None:
    eventBody['Color'] = eventColor
```

---

> is there a way to do this but for multiple variables without the use of multiple if statements? So instead of doing color is not None, description is not None doing it all with one single expression?

Yes. You could set all those entries in your dictionary, and then omit the ones that have the value None.

Something like this:

```
eventBody = {
          'Name': name,
          'Color': eventColor,
          'location': location,
          'description':description,
          'attendees': [],
}

eventBody = {k:v for (k,v) in eventBody.items() if v is not None}
```

Or if you only want to filter some specific keys, like this:

```
for key in ('Color', 'location', 'description'):
    if eventBody[key] is None:
        del eventBody[key]
```

Comment: Btw, is there a way to do this but for multiple variables without the use of multiple if statements?
So instead of doing color is not None, description is not None doing it all with one single expression?

Comment: @PeterPetigru Yes. I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`pass` is not an expression, it does not have a value. I would stick with the original (i.e., set `'Color': None`), but if you do not want `None`, you can just do a standard `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.update` method

```
   eventBody = {
              'Name': name, #EventName
              'location': location,
              'description':description,
              'attendees': [],
              }
if eventColor:
    eventBody.update({"Color": eventColor})
```

Comment: you can also assign the pair using the `[]` operator: `eventBody['Color'] = eventColor`. I never used `dict.update`

Comment: yes you are right @SomethingSomething I usually use `[]` too, but now `update` method came up to my mind initially :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use if statement inside the dict.

But, this will get your work done.

```
eventBody = {
      'Name': name,
      'location': location,
      'description':description,
      }
if eventColor:
    eventBody.update(Color=eventColor)
```